# C programming. These statements must appear the same number of times as input number

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, do-while

This program requires me to enter a number from 1 to 9 and with that number it has to print 3 different statements the same time as the number I entered. For example, if I input the number 5 all 3 statements must print 5 times each. The problem is when I enter a number it does not appear the same number of times as the number I entered.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int num;

printf("Please enter a number from 1 to 9= ");
scanf("%d", &num);
while (num <= 9) {
    printf("Owls go Hoot Hoot \n");
    num++;
}
for (num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
    printf("Programming is fun \n");
}
do {
    printf("Florida beaches are beautiful \n");
} while (num <= 9);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use num. Use another variable for your loops so that you don't end uo changing the user value.

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int num;

printf("Please enter a number from 1 to 9= ");
scanf("%d", &num);

int counter = 0;

while (counter <= num) {
    printf("Owls go Hoot Hoot \n");
    counter++;
}
for (counter = 1; counter<= num; counter++) {
    printf("Programming is fun \n");
}

counter = 0;

do {
    printf("Florida beaches are beautiful \n");

    counter ++;

} while (counter <= num);
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first loop, will add 1 to num each time and will print # of times that is equal to 9+1-num. change it to while(num>0) and change num++ to num--

the other loops - you initialize num to 1 in the second loop, how do you want it to keep any relation to the number you received? i would keep num as untouched variable and init another loop index variable to do the dirty work.

Answer (score 0):

You first while is changing the input itself in each each iteration, so it will be printed (9 - num +1)  times. 
The first if statement will print exactly as the number of iterations you defined. 
The third loop will never run since the num will be 9 at the end of the second loop.

You'll need to define another index for all your loops. 
While will be for example

```
Int i=0;

while( i <= num) {

print... 

i++;}
```